# How to run WordPress behind a reverse proxy so that extensions still can detect the path

Tags: proxy

We run a Webshop example.com and a WordPress server at wordpress.example.com

The WordPress Server is connected to the main domain via a reverse proxy.

```
    ProxyPass /blog https://wordpress.example.com
    ProxyPassReverse /blog https://wordpress.example.com
```

This works quite okay. But some modules i.e. AMP cannot detect the sub path.

See also this question on the wordpress forum:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/relamphtml-url-with-proxy/#post-12228181

What is the proper way to run wordpress behind such a proxy? Is there a better way to configure the proxy or the plugin?

Comment: Is there a reason WP doesn't know that it's at `/blog`? Or that `/blog` isn't in the site URL? Then just go to yoursite.com/blog for WP, and yoursite.com/blog/wp-admin etc No weird rewriting necessary, everything gets the right URL first time around

Answer (score 0):

The following setup could work:

- on wordpress.example.com make Apache listen to example.com as well
- put the blog into the same subdirectory
- proxy pass ProxyPass /blog https://wordpress.example.com
- ProxyPreserveHost On

so the REQUEST_URI viewed from the wordpress host would be actually the real URL which was requested from the front proxy.